# Need help identifying 2011 Lego bag #3, Friends mini-doll legs with dark green pants with brown shoes and dark red bricks?

Tags: set-identification, friends

Trying to figure out what set this bag #3 from a 2011 set is from, unable to upload picture due to size limit.  Bag has a figure that is not like traditional LEGO figures, green pants, bends at the legs, brown shoes with feet that look like a real persons legs, then shoes, hair is brown and looks like a hedgehog piece of hair, with pointy ears, body is green with a gold belt and a tattoo on left arm.  Several silver pillars and purple and pink in bag.

[image: bag pic]

Answer (score 7):

The minifig is a Friends doll, to be precise, it's [Farran Leafshade](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=elf006&name=Farran%20Leafshade,%20Dark%20Green%20Trousers&category=%5BElves%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) from the Elves theme.

[image]

He [appears in two sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?M=elf006&in=S) in those green pants. Given that you mention the bag you have has #3 printed on it, and the 41076 Farran and the Crystal Hollow set has only 2 bags in it, I believe you have part of set  [41075 The Elves' Treetop Hideaway](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=41075-1#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) in your possession.

[image]

As an FYI: The 2011 printed on the bag indicates the year the bag design was copyrighted - it has no correlation with the year the set was made (which was 2015 for the set in question).

Comment: Wow, awesome, thanks so much.  And thanks for the tip about the bag!!

Comment: You're welcome. Please use Stack Exchange's system of upvoting and marking an answer as accepted if you believe my answer is correct and adds value to your question. Thanks!